# echo something only once in infinite loop on php (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a (Laravel) command. the command is doing curl to a website, it's some kind of site checker. when the server is down I want to echo out something but it should be only once.

tried this code. doesn't work. it keeps echo ing. and now I'm getting stuck.

```php
class Monitoring extends Command {
     protected $signature = 'run:monitoring';

     private $state;

     public function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();
    
         $this->state = false;
     }

     public function handle() {
         while (true) {
            if (!$this->isMyServerAlive()) {
                $this->state = true;

                if ($this->state) {
                    echo 'THE SERVER IS DOWN!!!';
                }
            } else {
                $this->state = false;
            }
        }
         
     }

     private function isMyServerAlive() {
         return false; // let's say the server is down
     }

}
```

I know the code above will keep echoing.

The goal is when the `isMyServerAlive()` function returns to true from `false` and returns to true again, it will be echoing only once for second time, and so on and so forth.

I hope this message is clear.

Any better workaround than this?

Comment: and on what condition would it start actually echoing again or checking again?  also is doing this check only once a minute to large of an interval? if not i would set this up as a task

Comment: isMyServerAlive is always false, so the first if statement is always ran. Then you set state to true, so your next if statement is actually always true, so it keeps on echoing...

Comment: so what is the solution? using DB?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do... the code works as written. but your if statements ar both true, all the time, so it echos every time..

Comment: I updated the post. hope that's clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a variable which you toggle that will determine whether or not to echo out your message.

Initially you would want it be `true` so that when your server becomes unavailable it triggers the message. You then set it to `false` to prevent the message being triggered again until the value is set back to `true`.

So something like;

```
private $shouldNotify = true;

public function handle() {
    while (true) {
    
        // if the server is unavailable and,
        // a notification has not been trigger for this instance
        if (!$this->isMyServerAlive() && $this->shouldNotify) {

            // echo notification 
            echo 'The server is down';

            // set it so that a notification is not triggered on next loop
            $this->shouldNotify = false;
        }

        // if the server is again available
        // set it to trigger a notification when it becomes unavailable again
        if ($this->isMyServerAlive()) {
            $this->shouldNotify = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You would be better [scheduling this as a task](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling) rather than constantly looping.

Comment: consider using a static method and member variable to improve performance.

Comment: @TylerMiles That's an optimisation that should be investigated if there are performance issues with the code. PHP 7 made improvements in performance between static and non static functions to the point that depending on what you're doing, non static can be more performant. Different scenarios can have different outcomes, performance enhancements should be based on benchmarking your code rather than simply applying a pattern because someone said so.

Comment: Generally, I agree with you @Peppermintology; object access used to be faster than array access until the new hash table implementation. This is an infinite loop in a single method which will indefinitely stay on the call stack. I have confidence in the generalization here. I try to keep my application entirely functional and non objective in nature. Though php's language is bound to change again and who knows who will be right 'forever'...

Comment: [obects take more memory](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.performance-considerations.php) I realize that comment make it sound like I agree with Pepper on the object speed. I do not. I only agree on the idea of benchmarking to be sure. [php's new hash](https://www.npopov.com/2014/12/22/PHPs-new-hashtable-implementation.html) You should read both of these fully. Unfortunately, php had a lot of legacy information and practices still myth-ing themselves around the internet. The only way to `really` be in the know is [following the change log](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-8.php)